# Charge destination based tax on virtual products

Tags: magento2, tax-calculation, virtual-products

More and more U.S. states are requiring merchants to collect sales tax on digital goods, however I cannot figure out how to get Magento to include tax on virtual and downloadable products when tax is configured to be calculated on shipping address:

[image: Tax Calculation Based On configuration setting]

Even if we assign a "Taxable Goods" or some similar tax class to the product, sales tax is not charged because orders for virtual and downloadable products do not include a shipping address.

How can Magento be configured to collect sales tax on these types of products in states where the tax calculation is destination based?